# How do I use Jammit with EJS javascript templates?

Tags: jammit, ejs

Has anyone used Jammit with EJS javascript templates?  I can't figure out how I should load a new template with jammit.  It's causing me caching issues.

Here is how you would normally load a template.  Not sure how I would do it using Jammit.
http://code.google.com/p/embeddedjavascript/wiki/Templates
html = new EJS({url: '/template.ejs'}).render(data)